# Visual Studio 2013 ruins CSS in Debug

Tags: css, asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2012

Couldn't find answer to this question, and as this happened 2nd time, decided that it would be wise to write this here.

Problem: While debugging ASP.NET website, some CSS is rendering wrong. Or not rendering at all.

Edit: It seems, that the same problem also somehow caused following problem - in debug `GridTelerik.SelectedItems` was shown as null, when it really should contain values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason: Browser Link, that by default is enabled ([Description what it is](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013/))

Solution: Just disable it:

[image]